# Yii2 связь многие ко многим поиск по тегам

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, теги

Имею достаточно стандартную схему - картинки и теги, связанные между собой связью многие ко многим. На сайте нужно сделать поиск картинок по выбранным тегам, создал я [**страничку со списком тегов**](https://dota.gallery/site/search) каждому тегу добавил атрибут tag-id который содержит id тега. Сделал добавление класса Active при клике на тег.

**Вопрос №1:** как мне сделать так, что бы по команде (доустим нажата кнопка) все значения атрибутов tag-id у блоков, которые имеют класс Active, считывались и попадали в (допустим) массив?

Далее допустим я получил массив $tags, который содержит в себе id тегов, выбранных для поиска, допустим их будет три

```
Array(
[0] => 24
[1] => 12
[2] => 5)
```

Но что дальше? Как объяснить системе, что нужно искать картинки, которые имеют теги с выбранными id? Искать нужно картинки, а теги это ведь совсем другая таблица в БД. Единственное, что я нашёл, это использование связи как вызова к БД.

```
public function getArts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Art::className(), ['id' => 'art_id'])->viaTable('art_tag', ['tag_id' => 'id']);
}

public function getTagArts()
{
    return $this->getArts()->asArray()->all();
}
```

Но это работает только если в поиске указан только один тег, поэтому в случае указания трёх тегов, я просто делал поиск для каждого по отдельности и потом соединял всё это в массив.

```
foreach($tags as $tag)
        {
            $search = Tag::findOne($tag);
            $result[] = $search->getTagArts();
        }
```

и таким образом поиск по трём тегам в отдельности [**превращается в это**](https://dota.gallery/site/search?tags=24-12-5) (для запроса использовался $_GET. И вроде всё нормально, для получения конечного результата нужно просто найти совпадения (в данном примере - картинка с id = 66).

**Вопрос №2:** а как совпадения-то искать? Массив-то трёхуровневый получается! Не нашёл я в документации PHP подходящих функций. А что будет, когда на сайте разместятся 12 000 картинок и у каждой по 3-5 тегов? Это же запрос по 3-4 тегам потребует миллионов сравнений! Может мне пересмотреть подход к поиску? Может я что-то упустил?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Определите в модели с картинками отношение, по аналогии с

```
public function getArts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Art::className(), ['id' => 'art_id'])->viaTable('art_tag', ['tag_id' => 'id']);
}
```

У вас есть массив id тегов, осталось составить условие

```
Arts::find()
    ->joinWith('tags')
    ->where(['tags.id'=>$tagsIds])
    ->all();
```

[Документация](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#joining-with-relations)

P.S. Код писал без проверки, если не работает, придется поправить =)

Comment: Ммм, вот про такой запрос я не знал. Потребовалось время, что бы понять что к чему и как в нём что работает. Отдельное спасибо за ссылку на документацию. Запрос дейсвительно работает, хотя я до сих пор полностью не понимаю как, выводит более информативный массив, принимает массив тегов, но с некоторой особенностью, которая отличается от требований. Если указать для поиска теги id = 2, 3 то вместо того, что бы найти картинки, содержащие оба этих тега, он находит все картинки с этими тегами, даже если в них нет либо первого, либо второго тега.

Comment: Если указать для поиска теги id = 2, 3 то вместо того, что бы найти картинки, содержащие оба этих тега, он находит все картинки с этими тегами, даже если в них нет либо первого, либо второго тега. Вот сижу и думаю, как на него повлиять =/

Comment: Ну да, теперь всё тот же самый запрос https://dota.gallery/site/search?tags=24-12-5 выводит арты (не спорю, теперь красиво и даже со списком тегов для каждого). Но захватывает даже те, которые содержат лишь один из выбранных тегов.

Comment: как быстрое решение - пробежать массив и отфильтровать.

Comment: Вполне. Пришлось изрядно пораскинуть мозгами, что бы придумать как сортировать такой массив, но результаты вполне отвечают требованиям.